# div option value to form value

Tags: html, forms

We have built an html form which contains basic stuff with input and option fields. This works good!

Then we have some fields to choose an option:

```html
<h2 class="space">Franchise</h2>
<div class="spa2">
  <p option value="300" data-value="300" class="s2">300</p>
  <p option value="500" data-value="500" class="s2 selected">500</p>
  <p option value="1000" data-value="1000" class="s2">1000 </p>
  <p option value="1500" data-value="1500" class="s2">1500</p>
  <p option value="2000" data-value="2000" class="s2">2000 </p>
  <p option value="2500" data-value="2500" class="s2">2500</p>
</div>
```

This displays buttons are to choose specific values, but respective data is not transferred with POST because there are some non-html form type fields.

Is there a way to cheat and tell that this are form fields without change anything?

The code displays this buttons here:

[image: Display buttons]

Comment: Use a hidden input field for example and set it's value on click on the buttons according to the data-attribute, or use radio buttons and style them with a label, that should work too imho

Comment: If these are radio buttons or checkboxes then use radio buttons or checkboxes and style the labels.

Answer (score 0):

### Change them into `<form>` elements

You're asking the wrong question. This look can be achieved with form elements, which is easier and more reliable than "cheating".

#### HTML

```
<form>
  <input id="one" type="radio" name="choices" />
  <label for="one">300</label>

  <input id="two" type="radio" name="choices" />
  <label for="two">500</label>

  <input id="three" type="radio" name="choices" />
  <label for="three">1000</label>
</form>
```

- This example consists of radio inputs. Use this if there is only one choice, otherwise make the type `checkbox` if you can have multiple choices.
- The label should follow the input so that the corresponding label can be styled when the input is checked.
- The label is connected to its corresponding radio input with the matching `for` and `id` attributes.
- The radio input options are linked with the same `name="choices"` and only one option can be selected.

#### CSS

```
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background: red;
}
```

- Hide the radio buttons with `display: none`
- Style the labels that follow the radio buttons `input[type=radio] + label`
- Change the styles when a radio button is selected with `input[type=radio]:checked + label`
- Make the cursor a pointer with `cursor: pointer` on the labels

#### Full Example

```css
form {
  margin: 20px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]+label {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="one" type="radio" name="choices" />
  <label for="one">300</label>

  <input id="two" type="radio" name="choices" />
  <label for="two">500</label>

  <input id="three" type="radio" name="choices" />
  <label for="three">1000</label>
</form>
```